# probing individual klv streams for specific signature/header

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, key-value

Currently, the software I support processes the different streams within a video container (.ts, .mp4, .mpg, etc) without any issues as long as there is only one(1) type of each codec stream.

I've recently encountered a video sample that actually contains three(3) identified AV_CODE_ID_SMPTE_KLV streams.  As I loop through the three streams, one of them **is** the stream I need.
I haven't been able to figure out an easy way to do the specific query I need (check for known header bytes in the stream).

```
    ...
    for (i = 0; i < nb_streams; i++) {
       int real_stream_index = program ? program[i] : i;
       AVStream *st          = ic->streams[real_stream_index];
       AVCodecParameters *par = st->codecpar;
       if (par->codec_type != type)
          continue;
       if (id != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE) {
          if (par->codec_id != id)
             continue;
       }
       if (wanted_stream_nb >= 0 && real_stream_index != wanted_stream_nb)
          continue;
       if (type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO && !(par->channels && par->sample_rate))
          continue;
       disposition = !(st->disposition & (AV_DISPOSITION_HEARING_IMPAIRED | AV_DISPOSITION_VISUAL_IMPAIRED));
       count = st->codec_info_nb_frames;
       bitrate = par->bit_rate;
       multiframe = FFMIN(5, count);
       if ((best_disposition >  disposition) ||
           (best_disposition == disposition && best_multiframe >  multiframe) ||
           (best_disposition == disposition && best_multiframe == multiframe && best_bitrate >  bitrate) ||
           (best_disposition == disposition && best_multiframe == multiframe && best_bitrate == bitrate && best_count >= count))
          continue;
       best_disposition = disposition;
       best_count   = count;
       best_bitrate = bitrate;
       best_multiframe = multiframe;
       ret          = real_stream_index;
```

My thought was to add another || to the complex if{} above, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do the comparison I need (looking for the header bytes).

I've looked into existing documentation, and thought that accessing the probe_data structure within the AVStream contained within the AVFormatContext structure would give me the first few bytes of the stream.  No such luck, as the probe_data structure is empty even though we've done a probe on the file itself.

```
fprintf(stderr, "Filename: %s\t buf_size: %d\n", st-> probe_data.filename, st-> probe_data.buf_size);
```